# get element by second child ID

Tags: element

I want to change the second ID "myDIV" second p tag(index 4) class "child" backgropund color. But my script does not work. How to get the second child ID?

```
<div id="myDIV">
  <p class="child">First p element with class="child" in a div (index 0).</p>
  <p class="child">Second p element with class="child" in a div (index 1).</p>
  <p class="child">Third p element with class="child" in a div (index 2).</p>
</div>

<div id="myDIV">
  <p class="child">First p element with class="child" in a div (index 3).</p>
  <p class="child">Second p element with class="child" in a div (index 4).</p>
  <p class="child">Third p element with class="child" in a div (index 5).</p>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV")[1];
    x.getElementsByClassName("child")[2].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Element IDs should be unique within the entire document.

You can replace id="myDIV" with class="myDiv"

Then change your script as

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myDIV")[1];
x.getElementsByClassName("child")[1].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
</script>
```

```html
<div class="myDIV">
  <p class="child">First p element with class="child" in a div (index 0).</p>
  <p class="child">Second p element with class="child" in a div (index 1).</p>
  <p class="child">Third p element with class="child" in a div (index 2).</p>
</div>

<div class="myDIV">
  <p class="child">First p element with class="child" in a div (index 3).</p>
  <p class="child">Second p element with class="child" in a div (index 4).</p>
  <p class="child">Third p element with class="child" in a div (index 5).</p>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myDIV")[1];
    x.getElementsByClassName("child")[1].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
</script>
```